# change color or radio button using jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

In android phonegap application i need to change the color of the selected radio button center circle using jquery as i am having blue background for the html page.How to do this.

Here is my code:

```
input[type=radio]:active
{
 background-color:orange
}
```

I have tried the above code,but it doesn't help me.Please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using JQuery Mobile?
There is a great [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the background color of radio buttons themselves, but you can create your own custom radio buttons.

See this example:
http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/